# Simple Replication on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication

I created two tables on a database and I need to replicate them to another database but on the same machine. How can I do this?

Obs:

```
CREATE TABLE cities1 ( city varchar(80) primary key, location point );

CREATE TABLE weather10 ( city varchar(80) references cities1(city), temp_lo int, temp_hi int, prcp real, date date )

INSERT INTO weather VALUES ('San Francisco', 46, 50, 0.25, '1994-11-27');//insere uma linha na tabela com os dados

INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('San Francisco', '(-194.0, 53.0)');
```

Comment: take a look at [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61210/replicating-some-tables-from-one-postgres-database-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

If the tables already exist in database1 and database2:

On database 1:

```
psql database1
copy cities1 to '/tmp/cities1.copy';
copy weather10 to '/tmp/weather10.copy';
```

On database 2:

```
psql database2
truncate cities1, weather10;
copy cities from '/tmp/cities1.copy';
copy weather10 from '/tmp/weather10.copy';
```

Or, from the command line, assuming database2 exists, but the tables don't exist in database2:

```
pg_dump database1 -tcities1 -tweather10 | psql database2
```

If the tables already exist in database2, but they are not populated:

```
pg_dump -a database1 -tcities1 -tweather10 | psql database2
```

If the tables already exist and have data in them in database2:

```
echo 'truncate cities, weather10;' > /tmp/tfile
pg_dump -a database1 -tcities1 -tweather10 >> /tmp/tfile
psql database2 -f /tmp/tfile
rm /tmp/tfile
```

You can even use foreign wrappers or dblink to make the copy operation entirely in database1.

Another thing that comes to mind, you can create the two databases and replicate one to the other, this will do the entire database, not just the two tables.

If you just need the same data in a second database, you could create a foreign wrapper in the second database which simply references the data in the first database (without copying it).

There are probably other ways :-)

Good Luck,
-g